# How do I get an Ampersand symbol into Word 2007 .docx XML file?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, docx

I am generating a Word doc in xml based on customer input, and of course it blows up whenever an `&` is used. I tried replacing all instances of `&` with `&amp;`, but then `&amp;` literally shows up in my Word Doc. Here's my code:

```
        static String replace(String in) {
            String ampersand = "&(?![a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?;)";
            return in.replaceAll(ampersand,"&amp;");
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the code being used?  How are you generating the XML?

Comment: I just have a docx document serving as a template with some strings as placeholders which I replace with the user given strings.

Comment: why not replacing & by && ? I think & must be a delimiter for something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the ampersand is escaped differently in TOC and the title.

In TOC, it is escaped as `&amp;` while in the title is escaped as `\u0026`.

Solution is to escape ampersand differently in TOC and title:

- TOC: html escaping sequence
- TITLE: unicode escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing the ampersand with `&#38;` or `&#x0026;` (unicode)?

Answer (score 0):

Word 2007 itself does &, so your problem must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions seems wrong to me. Why don't you just do:

```
    static String replace(String in) {
        return in.replace("&","&amp;");
    }
```

Comment: Because if I called that function twice, I would get &amp;amp;

Comment: Okey, lets consider you call it just once, would it work then? In this case you definetely are using the wrong regular expression.